# Python MongoDB Nested Group Query

Tags: python, json, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a really basic questions for you. My documents like this;

```
{'_id': ObjectId('60c6f765483c161ebeffa5c3'),
'User': 'bayram3932',
'Tweet': '@hfa01 #egeen 1350 üstüne atmalı ,
'Date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 14, 9, 29, 57, 474000),
'Analysis': {'Polarity': 0.0, 'Subjectivity': 0.0, 'Result': 'Neutral'},
'Ticker': 'EGEEN',
'Translated': '1350 HTTPS T CO B NT KR Q FWG W'},
{'_id': ObjectId('60c6f76e483c161ebeffa5c4'),
'User': 'Borsatakip56',
'Tweet': 'Herkese günaydın. Bol bereketli, bol kazançlı bir hafta olsun inşallah.. #XU100  #bist100',
'Date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 14, 9, 30, 6, 401000),
'Analysis': {'Polarity': 0.7,
'Subjectivity': 0.6000000000000001,
'Result': 'Positive'},
'Ticker': 'XU100',
'Translated': 'Good morning everybody Plenty of luxuries plenty of professors get a week instruction XU 100 Bi st 100'},
{'_id': ObjectId('60c6f770483c161ebeffa5c5'),
'User': 'hisselog',
'Tweet': 'Teknosa İç ve Dış Ticaret A.Ş. #TKNSA, $TKNSA #BorsaIstanbul #BIST100 #BIST30 #BIST',
'Date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 14, 9, 30, 8, 224000),
'Analysis': {'Polarity': -0.125,
'Subjectivity': 0.125,
'Result': 'Negative'},
'Ticker': 'TKNSA',
'Translated': 'Tek nos a Interior and Foreign Trade Inc TK NSA BI ST 100 BI ST 30'},
```

I wanna query like this dataframe;
[I wanna query like this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txRrN.png)

In other words, I want to query and group positivity, negativity, and neutrality for all tickers.

```
hours = 3
sentiment_pipeline = [{"$match": 
                            {"Date": {"$gte":datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours = hours),"$lte":datetime.datetime.now()},
                                   "Analysis.Result":"Negative"
                            }
                    },
                  {"$group":{"_id":"$Ticker", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}
                 ]
```

The pipeline above shows my attempt. I can easily find and count the negative ones in the last three hours, but I want to do this for all polarity types at once.

If I do 3 separate query like this;

```
sentiment_pipeline = [{"$match": 
                        {"Date": {"$gte":datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours = hours),"$lte":datetime.datetime.now()},
                               ***"Analysis.Result":"Positive"***
                        }
                },
              {"$group":{"_id":"$Ticker", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}
             ]
```

and

```
sentiment_pipeline = [{"$match": 
                    {"Date": {"$gte":datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours = hours),"$lte":datetime.datetime.now()},
                           ***"Analysis.Result":"Neutral"***
                    }
            },
          {"$group":{"_id":"$Ticker", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}
         ]
```

it doesn't look so good. How can i do?

Comment: Better you need to post you codes as snippets, not image!!

Comment: The table in image type. I edited the documents image as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$group` by `Ticker` and Result fields and get sum of `Polarity`
- `$group` by the only `Ticker` and construct an array of `Result` and `Polarity` in key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value pair array of object to object

```
sentiment_pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      Date: { 
        $gte: datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours = hours),
        $lte:datetime.datetime.now() 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Ticker: "$Ticker",
        Result: "$Analysis.Result"
      },
      Polarity: { $sum: "$Analysis.Polarity" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.Ticker",
      Analysis: {
        $push: { k: "$_id.Result", v: "$Polarity" }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { Analysis: { $arrayToObject: "$Analysis" } } }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfWiojHSgUi)

Comment: Thank you for your answet but the real output that i want to see is that `    [
    {
      "Analysis": {
        "Neutral": 20,
         "Positive": 10,
          "Negative": 15
       },
      "_id": "EGEEN"
    },
    {
      "Analysis": {
        "Neutral": 20,
         "Positive": 13,
          "Negative": 3
     },
     "_id": "TKNSA"
    },
    {
      "Analysis": {
        "Neutral": 50,
         "Positive": 58,
          "Negative": 112
      },
     "_id": "XU100"
    }
   ]`

Comment: there is no other result in data for _id, so it will return available status.

Comment: check in playground data, the `_id: XU100` have only one result which is `Positive` there is no other result, check with your real data.

Comment: thanks for your help, i did some basic changes on your query and finally solve the problem, thanks again.